# jms serializer custom behavior via annotation

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, jmsserializerbundle

I have a very big entity with a lot of number values. Because most of these values have a unit, I created a `@Unit` annotation to put that right into the model. Now I want to Serialize that entity.

Let's assume an entity like this:

```
class Entity {

  /**
   * @var string
   *
   * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
   * @Assert\NotBlank()
   */
  private $name;

  /**
   * @ORM\Column(type="smallint", nullable=true)
   * @Unit("m")
   */
  private $distance;
}
```

The output looks something like this:

```
{
  "name": "bla",
  "distance": 1.20
}
```

I want it to look like this:

```
{
  "name": "bla",
  "distance": {"value": 1.20, "unit": "m", "string": "1.20 m"}
}
```

I tried to use a custom handler but there is no way to call the default handler as far as I know.

```
public function handler(JsonSerializationVisitor $visitor, $data, array $type, Context $context)
{
    $result = $context->accept($data);
    // result is empty
    // i can add stuff here but not call the default handler
    return $result;
}
```

So how can I extend (not overwrite) the default behavior?

EDIT: I also tried pre- and post serialization event which doesn't work either because it seems the serializer assumes the type before calling the handler.

Answer (score 0):

```
class EntitySubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [
            [
                'event' => 'serializer.post_serialize',
                'method' => 'onPostSerialize',
                'class' => Entity::class,
           ],
       ];
    }
    public function onPostSerialize(ObjectEvent $event)
    {
        $entity = $event->getObject();
        /** @var \JMS\Serializer\JsonSerializationVisitor $visitor */
        $reader    = new AnnotationReader();
        // todo: read Unit annotation
        $visitor = $event->getVisitor();
        $visitor->addData('distance', 'some value');
    }
}
```